# how to set up a for loop where the only thing that changes is the id

Tags: jquery, arrays, class, for-loop, onclick

I have a bunch of jquery functions that I know would be better utilized in a for loop, but every time I try to set it up, it doesn't work.

Here is what I want the for loop to do:

```
$("episode1").click(
function () {
    if ($("#episode2").hasClass('clicked')) {
        $("#episode2").removeClass('clicked');
    }
    else if ($("#episode3").hasClass('clicked')) {
        $("#episode3").removeClass('clicked');
    }
    else if ($("#episode4").hasClass('clicked')) {
        $("#episode4").removeClass('clicked');
    }
    else if ($("#episode5").hasClass('clicked')) {
        $("#episode5").removeClass('clicked');
    }
    else if ($("#episode6").hasClass('clicked')) {
        $("#episode6").removeClass('clicked');
    }
    else if ($("#episode7").hasClass('clicked')) {
        $("#episode7").removeClass('clicked');
    }
    else if ($("#episode8").hasClass('clicked')) {
        $("#episode8").removeClass('clicked');
    }
    else if ($("#rogueone").hasClass('clicked')) {
        $("#rogueone").removeClass('clicked');
    }
    else if ($("#solo").hasClass('clicked')) {
        $("#solo").removeClass('clicked');
    }
});
```

how would I set the array up? just by the id tags?

Comment: Give them all a common class, other than `clicked`, and then it's a simple `$('.otherClass.clicked').removeClass('clicked');`

Comment: @Taplar `else if` means he only wants to remove the first one, not all of them.

Comment: I feel like that is an assumption.  Assuming he's not just trying to find which ever one was clicked.  Can you clarify this @BrookeMortensen

Comment: they all have the class of "episodescroll", but I don't want the class of the episode I'm pressing on the lose the class "clicked"

Comment: Updated my answer with a version that uses `not()` to exclude the element clicked.

Comment: @BrookeMortensen But do you want to remove the `clicked` class from all of them or just the first one that has that class?

Comment: An extension of that question, is it ever a valid case that two of those elements should have the `clicked` class?

Comment: I want to remove it from all of them, but the idea is that only one of the elements will ever have the 'clicked' class, because when you click on a different one it will remove it from the other one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give them all a common class, other than `clicked`, and then it's a simple

```
$('.episodescroll.clicked').removeClass('clicked');
```

If you want to exclude the one you just clicked on then you can do:

```
$('.episodescroll.clicked').not(this).removeClass('clicked');
```

Otherwise you can just select multiple elements.

```
$("#episode2, #episode3, #episode4").removeClass('clicked');
```

I would suggest going the first route though.

Comment: $('.episodescroll.clicked').not(this).removeClass('clicked'); worked perfectly. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over an array of IDs, and stop when you find the first one that matches your criteria.

```
const ids = ["episode2", "episode3", "episode4", "episode5", "episode6", "episode7", "episode8", "rogueone", "solo"];
$.each(ids, function(i, id) {
    if ($("#" + id).hasClass("clicked")) {
        $("#" + id).removeClassClass("clicked");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Returning `false` from the callback function ends the loop.

But if the order of the elements in the DOM is the same as the order in the array, you can simplify it to:

```
$(".episodescroll.clicked").not(this).first().removeClass("clicked");
```

Comment: @Taplar I considered that, but that will use the DOM ordering, not the order in the array. It's likely that they're the same, but I didn't want to assume.

Comment: thanks for both of your help! I really appreciate it!